# Android Studio подчеркивает переменные серым цветом

Tags: android-studio

Почему Android Studio подчеркивает переменные info, format?

В swith предупреждение о возможном null. Задание учебное и ничем, никем не используется. Но тем не менее, это нужно обыграть как-то особенно или предупреждение будет висеть все время? Добавление ветки default или try-catch предупреждение не убирают.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Это проверка на граматику.

Comment: Грамматика подчеркивается зеленым. Из того кода, что приведен (без default), info и format действительно могут быть null. А вообще - и intent.getAction() может быть null. Попробуйте прописать перед ним что-то типа assert (intent) != null;

Comment: у вас в switch обработаны не все случаи. Добавьте default поведение

Comment: @Jarvis_J перед switch проверкой if (info != null) предупреждение уходит, благодарю.

Comment: @UjinUkr что значит грамматика? Эти слова не пересекаются с зарезервированными. Я хоть икс сделаю, подчеркнет.

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский с default предупреждение не уходит

Comment: Грамматика в данном случае означает наличие слова в словаре английского языка, а не пересечение с зарезервированным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ найден. Подчеркивание переменной есть цветовая настройка редактора. В данном случае для переназначенной переменной.

Нужно снять галку Effects. Убрать можно здесь:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Java -> Variables ->
>   Reassigned local variable

Источник: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963949/kotlin-why-are-most-variables-underlined-in-android-studio-and-how-do-i-turn-th/34964282#34964282), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443871/variables-with-underline)

На второй вопрос дан ответ в комментариях. Необходимо до switch реализовать проверку на null.